# Recovering data from a UFS drive with bad superblock

Tags: data-recovery, zfs, ufs

I've got a UFS drive that has a bad superblock. I've used mke2fs to find the alternate superblocks. The drive has a zfs_member on it named "james". How can I mount the drive with the alternate superblock. If I try to normally mount it, it gives the error "unknown filesystem type 'zfs_member'." I'm using ArchLinux.

Additional drive details:

- x86 boot sector
- partition 1:

  - ID: 0xee
  - Starthead: 255
  - Start sector: 1
  - Sectors: 312581807
  - Offset: 0x0

Comment: Your question does not include the needed information: What do you understand by a "UFS drive"? Why do you name a partition with an EFI header marker? Partitions with an EFI marker are typically not using UFS as filesystem.